# Is it possible to exchange information between arduino and android phones easily using nrf24l01?

Tags: arduino, rf, radio, android, nrf24l01

I need to send information from arduino to an android phone, having some app actively listening for radio communication from arduino. Using nrf24l01 is that possible?

The best scenario would be direct communication, even without any type of handshake. Arduino sends a number sequence that android expects to receive, and the app alerts me when it ears that sequence.

Comment: If your android has BTLE, limited communication of short one-way messages is possible by handcrafting packet buffers with BTLE-compatible encoding, even though that is not what the nrf chip was designed for.

Answer (score 0):

Another method: You could create a Wifi hotspot with your Android, have the arduino connect to it, and have them communicate that way.

You'd need the ESP8266 for the arduino.  They cost $5 each.

Juggs

Answer (score 0):

nrf24L01 ICs use the SPI protocol. This is easily implemented with an Arduino but probably requires special knowledge to implement on an Android system.

As JR says - an ESP8266 based transceiver will "talk t" and Android phone and can be controlled by an Arduino.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible . You need to pair your BT device with your android device for once which will make your further communications possible without handshakes .If you can be more clear on what you wanna send and receive I can give you references .

Comment: The OP was asking about nrf24l01, which is not a BT device.

Comment: While not a BT device, short message one-way advertising communication from an NRF24L01 to a BTLE receiver is a documented hack.  But no pairing is involved.